# Channels edit history illegible on mobile

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web, revision-history, stack-overflow-for-teams

When I click the "edited by..." link on a post in Channels, I don't see a colored diff. Instead, both the removed and the added text displays identically. So where a traditional text-only `wdiff` would render

```
text with [-removed-]{+added+} words
```

I only see

```
text with removedadded words
```

with no coloring or other hints to show whether something is unchanged, removed, or added.

(I have a screen shot from Safari on IOS, and another from my preferred IOS browser, Grazing, but because this is in private beta still, I'm not sure how much I can reveal. This should be easy enough to repro anyway, I hope.)

Comment: Should the downvote be interpreted as "please stop providing feedback" or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: people like working in broken environments.

Comment: Don't interpret votes, they make no sense.

Comment: Yesterday the US went through the daylight savings time change, which makes you lose an hour of sleep - don't know if the downvote came from here but maybe someone just was in a really bad mood ;)

Comment: Yeah, I was only asking in the vain hope that the downvoter would revisit and maybe explain themselves. I fully expect downvotes on *everything* I post on Meta but it's still curious that the first feedback on all my recent posts was a downvote, and I suppose it would be useful to be able to discern whether it means "I dont like [channels]" or "I don't like *you"* or perhaps the ultimate "I don't like Meta".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice catch! The styling for showing deletions as red and additions as green has been brought in to the view for Channels revision histories, this should be live as of a few minutes ago.